# Union Behaviour

Tags: c++, class, unions

Is it possible to get the following behavior out of a Union?

```
class A : public Base //Base is an abstract base class.
{
  public:
    A( int );
    virtual void foo() //A virtual function from Base.
    {
      //I don't want to have to specify if it's oneOption or twoOption.
      // I would like it to just call whichever one's is defined in mData.
      mData.foo();
    }
  private:
    union B
    {
      C oneOption; //A class which inherits from Base.
      D twoOption; //Another class which inherits from Base.
    } mData;
};
```

Basically, I would like to have a class containing a Union of derived classes. Then I would like to implement all the virtual functions base class in terms of my Union.

I can try to rephrase this if it's too confusing.

Thanks

Comment: I would have a bash at rephrasing it.

Comment: That's what pointers are for :) `Base *mData` with proper assignments should do the trick.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Technically you can, the syntax is correct and the compiler will let you treat both instance variables as you'd expect (with the same constraints that applies in general to unions).

In practice it seems unnecessary when there is mutual exclusion, you can easily use a pointer to an instance:

```
CommonAncestor *mData;
```

I can see many maintainability issues by using constructs that were meant to be used when polymorphism didn't exist in the language.

Comment: Yeah, that makes perfect sense. Now I feel silly for not thinking about just using a pointer like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Members of a union are not allowed to have constructors.

You can do something like this:

```
void PickC() { new (oneOption) C; }
void PickD() { new (twoOption) D; }
C * GetC() { return (C*) oneOption; }
D * GetD() { return (D*) twoOption; }

private:

union B
{
  char oneOption[ sizeof(C) ]; //A class which inherits from Base.
  char twoOption[ sizeof(D) ]; //Another class which inherits from Base.
} mData;
```

But it is seriously ugly.

Comment: This definitely does the trick, and I agree it's ugly. Thanks for your help.